# Is Z3 Max SMT Optimization suited for minimizing violated constraints?

Tags: optimization, z3, smt, z3py

I'm trying to solve a system of linear equations with the additional constraint that each variable should stem from a small finite set of numbers.

In my case however, this cannot be true for all variables as then the there would exist no solution. Thus I tried to formulate it as a Max-SMT problem where I want to maximize the number of variables stemming from their respective set. Doing this for many variables resulted in a far from optimal solution.

An example would be:

```
(declare-fun B () Int)
(declare-fun A () Int)
(declare-fun D () Int)
(declare-fun C () Int)
(declare-fun E () Int)
(assert (= (- (+ 0 (* 1 C) (* 1 D)) (+ 0 (* 1 A) (* 1 B))) 0))
(assert (= (- (+ 0 (* 1 E)) (+ 0 (* 1 D) (* 2 C))) 0))
(assert (= (- (+ 0 (* 1 D)) (+ 0 (* 1 E) (* 1 A))) 0))
(assert-soft (or (= A 0) (= A 1) (= A 2)) :weight 10)
(assert-soft (or (= B 0) (= B (- 1))) :weight 10)
(assert-soft (or (= C 0) (= C (- 1)) (= C (- 2))) :weight 10)
(assert-soft (or (= D 0) (= D 2)) :weight 10)
(assert-soft (or (= E 5)) :weight 10)
(check-sat)
```

i.e. for A + B = C + D,

D + 2 C = E and

D = E + A:

A is in {0, 2}, B is in {0, -1}, C is in {0, -1, -2}, D is in {0, 2} and E = 5.

The optimal solution would be A = 2, B = -1, C = -1, D = 2 and E = 0.

For such a small example using Z3's Max-SMT works fine. When I tried scaling this up, using ~1000 variables and 2000 equations the check did return *sat* but the solution presented (~600 violated clauses) was far worse than a solution I reached using a simple greedy algorithm (~ 50 violated clauses).

Is this not a use-case for Z3 or am I using it wrong? I have used z3py to implement this with, unless stated otherwise, default settings.

Comment: z3 MaxSAT should solve this correctly; could be a bug. Please report it at: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues

Comment: Performance wise, for contiguous intervals it might be better to formulate the soft-clause as `(and (<= LOW x) (<= x UP))`. You may want to investigate whether Z3 is providing an incorrect answer by running a different OMT solver, or by conjoining your greedy model with the formula (without soft-clauses) and confirm that it is actually satisfiable.